# recaptcha not working on rails3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, recaptcha, omniauth

I am working on a new rails project and using device and omniauth recaptcha gem and i keep getting this message "cannot reach recaptch "

my controller code is as follows

```
def create
  if session[:omniauth] == nil #OmniAuth
    if verify_recaptcha
      super
      session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record? #OmniAuth
    else
      build_resource
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      flash[:notice] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code and click submit."
      render_with_scope :new
    end
  else
    super
    session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record? #OmniAuth
  end

end
```

Comment: why don't you like to accept answers?

Comment: im so sorry... maybe i get too excited to try out the solution